# I want to read a file which is on hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop

I have tried by giving path as" hdfs://localhost:9000/path to file" but still its not working is there any other way to read file? 
I want to give the file path in program,but not as an argument on terminal...

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information? How are you trying to read? What error are you getting? Please improve the question a little to let others know what is actually happening.

Comment: My Wordcount program output is in a file named psap.txt which is on hdfs and its path is user/hduser/ppp and i want to read that file.....

Comment: **How** do you want to read that file? Any code would be helpful

Comment: THis might help: http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/05/how-to-read-file-in-hdfs-using-hadoop_14.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have WebHDFS enabled (dfs.webhdfs.enabled set to true in hdfs-site.xml) then you can access the file with a simple REST call.  Many client libraries can open HTTP URI's directly.

For Java, follow the example in [Open stream from uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657687/open-stream-from-uri) and construct the URI for your file using the examples in the [WebHDFS REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Open_and_Read_a_File) documentation.  For example, I was able to open a file from HDFS on my cluster using the following URI: "`http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/sampledata/sample.log?op=OPEN`"

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is how read the contents of that file using Java code, then have a look at my answer: [Programatically reading contents of text file stored in HDFS using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22020734/394868).